# Does Python have a cached thread pool similar to java?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I am having difficulty finding something like Java's [Cached Threadpools](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executors-cached-fixed-threadpool) for python, and was wondering if it exists.

TLDR; the main point of a cached thread pool is to create as many threads as it needs to execute the task(s) it must execute. It maintains some list of threads; old threads will be reused, and new ones created if none are available. If a thread is not used in `x` seconds, it will be terminated and removed. It's kind of like an auto-scaling thread pool.

Comment: Python has threads, but they are not concurrent! Look up GIL. So there is no use for a cached thread pool, since everything will be one thread anyway.

Comment: @Sebastian Let's say their concurrency is very limited because of the GIL.

Comment: @Sebastian Interesting, never knew that. The only reason I wanted a threadpool was so I don't create a bunch of threads but... I guess, why not, right, if im not actually really creating threads...

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/concurrency_in_python/concurrency_in_python_pool_of_threads.htm ?